# Recursive parsing instead of using pop

Tags: python, recursion

How would I go about parsing tokens recursively, instead of using pop?

```
def parse(tokens, i = 0):
    """parse: tuple(String) * int -> (Node, int)
    From an infix stream of tokens, and the current index into the
    token stream, construct and return the tree, as a collection of Nodes, 
    that represent the expression.

    NOTE:  YOU ARE NOT ALLOWED TO MUTATE 'tokens' (e.g. pop())!!!  YOU
        MUST USE 'i' TO GET THE CURRENT TOKEN OUT OF 'tokens'
    """
    i = 0
    if tokens.pop(0) == '+':
        return mkAddNode(parse(tokens), parse(tokens))
    elif tokens.pop(0) == '-':
        return mkSubtractNode(parse(tokens), parse(tokens))
    ....
```

I'm struggling with converting this to using a recursive call, and not use `tokens.pop()` in the function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Increment `i` when calling `parse` recursively:

```
def parse(tokens, i=0):
    """parse: tuple(String) * int -> (Node, int)
    From an infix stream of tokens, and the current index into the
    token stream, construct and return the tree, as a collection of Nodes, 
    that represent the expression.

    NOTE:  YOU ARE NOT ALLOWED TO MUTATE 'tokens' (e.g. pop())!!!  YOU
        MUST USE 'i' TO GET THE CURRENT TOKEN OUT OF 'tokens'
    """
    if tokens[i] == '+':
        return mkAddNode(parse(tokens, i+1), parse(tokens, i+1))
    elif tokens[i] == '-':
        return mkSubtractNode(parse(tokens, i+1), parse(tokens, i+1))
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of actually popping, just look at the first element, and when calling recursively, make sure you strip off the first character:

```
# just doing the split once
first, remaining = tokens[0], tokens[1:]

if first == '+':
    return mkAddNode(parse(remaining), parse(remaining))
elif first == '-':
    return mkSubtractNode(parse(remaining), parse(remaining))
```

Or as I’m just now seeing that you are supposed to use the index `i`, you can also move the pointer with every recursive call; of course you don’t want to reset `i` to zero every time in the parse function then:

```
if tokens[i] == '+':
    return mkAddNode(parse(tokens, i + 1), parse(tokens, i + 1))
elif tokens[i] == '-':
    return mkSubtractNode(parse(tokens, i + 1), parse(tokens, i + 1))
```

In any way, you should also handle the situation that the token stream ended. For the index-based way this would be if `i > len(tokens)`.